# $watch not firing when service variables change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The `cart` directive has a `$watch` which watches `scope.items` for changes, which in turn is referenced from the `Cart` service. The watch never fires. I can get it to work by recalculating on `mouseenter` but I want a more robust solution.

```
.directive('cart', ['Cart', 'Catalogue', function(Cart, Catalogue){
return {
    templateUrl: './templates/cart.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.items = Cart.getItems;
        scope.$watch('items', function(){
            scope.total = Cart.total();
        });
        scope.catalogue = Catalogue;            
        element.bind('mouseenter', function(){
            //Can make it work by doing it inside here, but that doesn't seem right
            //scope.total = Cart.total();
            scope.$apply('showDropdown = true');
        });
        element.bind('mouseout', function(){    
            scope.$apply('showDropdown = false');
        })
    }
}
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the $watch method only watches for changes on the first level/layer of the object, to watch nested values you must have to add true as a second parameter:

```
scope.$watch('items', function(){
    scope.total = Cart.total();
}, true);
```

Comment: Thank you. I simply forgot that the default, shallow `$watch` doesn't care how many elements are in an array. Now that you've reminded me I've realized that `$watchCollection` would suffice.